# Convert Lotus 123 to Excel File to MS Access Using VB or PHP

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-access

I have a lotus 123 file exported to excel file. There is no problem converting from lotus to excel. The only problem that I am facing now is on how to convert it from excel to MS Access database.

The record is compose of several rows instead of one. The only sign that separate it from record to record is the equal sign.

Here is the sample record in excel file:

[image]

I want to create a Visual Basic program to automate the convertion but I don't know where to start. I also know PHP but wondering how to do it either.

Here's the sample file:

[Sample .xls file](http://jipsolution.com/tmp/sample.xls).

Comment: I don't know how to create a question that will not be flag as out of topic question. I saw similar a lot of post here that is not even descriptive but don't received negative votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data looks like it was prepared in some system before it was converted into a Lotus workbook. Try to locate the source system to see if the data is in a format that is easier to parse.

If that is not available, you may need to create a custom parser to read in lines until you reach the '=' delimiter and then join up blocks of text, trimming white space, to get the columns correctly aligned.

You could try saving the workbook in Tab delimited format and running the following

```
' ParseSheet.vbs

Dim fso, Text, Out

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Text = fso.OpenTextFile("sample.txt")
Set Out = WScript.StdOut

Dim Columns
Dim Delimiter
Dim Content()
Dim Tab
Dim Line

Tab = Chr(9)

Sub ParseLine(Line)
    Dim Column
    Dim Delimiter
    Dim Value

    Column = 1
    Line = Line & ":"   ' Ensure each row is terminated by the delimiter
    Do While Instr(Line, ":") > 0
        Value = Left(Line, Instr(Line, ":") - 1)
        Value = Replace(Value, Tab, "")
        ' Skip over column separators
        Column = Column + 1
        If Column > Columns Then
            Columns = Column
            ReDim Preserve Content(Columns) ' Grow array to match data
            Content(Columns) = ""
        End If
        If Left(Value, 1) = """" Then   ' Strip Quoted strings
            Value = Mid(Value, 2, Len(Value) - 2)
        End If
        If Len(Value) > 0 Then  ' Introduce space between most non-empty segments
            If (Len(Content(Column)) = 0) Or (Right(Content(Column), 1) = "/") Then
                Delimiter = ""
            Else
                Delimiter = " "
            End If
            Content(Column) = Content(Column) & Delimiter & Value
        End If
        Line = Mid(Line, Instr(Line, ":") + 1, Len(Line) - Instr(Line, ":"))
    Loop    
End Sub

Function Strip(Line)
    ' Canonicalise emphasised text
    Line = Replace(Line, "  ", "~")
    Line = Replace(Line, " ", "")
    Line = Replace(Line, "~", " ")
    Strip = Line
End Function

Sub WriteContent(Columns)
    Delimiter = ""
    For Column = 1 To Columns
        Out.Write Delimiter & Trim(Content(Column))
        Delimiter = Tab
        Content(Column) = ""
    Next
    Out.WriteLine
End Sub

ReDim Content(1)
Columns = 1
Content(1) = "Group"

Line = Text.ReadLine
Do While Not Text.AtEndOfStream
    If Left(Line, 1) = "=" Then
        Line = Text.ReadLine
        Do While Left(Line, 1) <> "="
            Call ParseLine(Line)
            ' Strip expanded columns
            For Column = 2 To 3
                Content(Column) = Strip(Content(Column))
            Next        
            Line = Text.ReadLine
        Loop

        Call WriteContent(Columns)

        Line = Text.ReadLine
        ' Read Group as special case
        Content (1) = Strip(Left(Line, Instr(Line, Tab) - 1))
        Line = Text.ReadLine
    Else 
        Line = Text.ReadLine
        Do While Left(Line, 1) <> "-"
            Call ParseLine(Line)
            Line = Text.ReadLine
        Loop

        Call WriteContent(Columns)
    End If
Loop
```

using `CScript ParseSheet.vbs //NoLogo sample.txt > sample.tab` to see roughly what is required.

The result is tab-delimited console output that unwraps the multi-line columns into single rows using the row delimiters, and incidentally removes the gratuitous spaces in the expanded headings.

This is not intended as a good example of code style of practice, but something that will do the job of a one-time conversion.

Comment: The data is coming from lotus 123. That's the output when I converted it to Excel. I am also considering a your suggestion in the 2nd paragraph. But that's too hard to create a program.

Comment: Check with the owner of the data again. The formatting of the workbook really suggests that some mainframe- or mini-computer was used to prepare the report from a asset register. It would really be easier if you can extract the unformatted data from the source and then process it more intelligently than trying to do things like change 'A R T I C L E' into 'ARTICLE'. Creating the program will be some work, but is not difficult. Get all the data to be processed to the developer from the start to avoid later surprises.

Comment: Even the source file when I open it in Lotus 123, the data is still the same. It was being format as multiple row in one record.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I didn't notice that you have updated your answer. It seems to be working fine. I will try to convert some of my data and I'll let you know the outcome. Thank you